# Getting a single point from a Mapbox polygon layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I want to render a polygon source in Mapbox as a symbol or a single point.

I currently have the following code:

```
  map.addLayer({
   'id': 'polygon_layer',
   'source':
      {
        'type': 'vector',
        'url': 'mapbox://user.source'
      },
   'source-layer': 'Polygon_Layer', 
   'type': 'circle',
   'paint': 
      {
        'circle-color': '#EEEEEE',
      }
  } );
```

This returns a circle at every vertex of the polygon. Is it possible to filter the source data to get just one point, or even a centroid location?